# How to display concatenated string and int in qlineedit or qtextedit?

Tags: c++, qlineedit

I have here:

```
int num = 000;
std::string result;
std::string text = "asdasd";
result += text + std::to_string(num);
```

I want to display the result in qlineedit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using [qt](/questions/tagged/qt), you should use `QString` instead of `std::string` to avoid many unnecessary conversions.
Indeed, `QString` is the string class used by all the Qt library (containers, ...).

Your sample will become then:

```
int num = 0;
QString text = "asdasd";
QString result = text + QString::number(num);
```

Then, you'll be able to write:

```
my_widget->setText(result); // QLineEdit or QTextEdit
```

---

If you really want to use a `std::string` anyway, you'll need to convert it to a proper `QString`. You could use [QString::fromStdString()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#fromStdString) for this purpose.

For example:

```
my_widget->setText(QString::fromStdString(result));
```